# node js spawn child process powershell Write-Output buffer size

Tags: javascript, node.js, powershell

I have a node js script that spawns a non-terminating powershell script and listens for data:

node js script:

```
"use strict";

const cp = require("child_process");

const psData = cp.spawn
("powershell -executionpolicy bypass  ./powershell-script.ps1", [], {
    shell: "powershell.exe",
    serialization: "json",
    windowsHide: true,
});

psData.stdout.on("data", function (_data) {
    try {
        const psObj = JSON.parse(_data);
        console.log(psObj);
    } catch (e) {
        console.error("Failed to Parse JSON!", e);
        console.log(_data.toString());
    }
});
```

powershell script:

```
function getData {
# some irrelevant code +
if ($readData -ne "") 
{
  $data = [ordered]@{
    type = "text";
    value = $readData;
  }
  $data = $data | ConvertTo-Json
  Write-Output  $data
}
}

while ($true) {
    gedData
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 250
}
```

The combination works fine up until $data in the ps script goes over a few kb, when that happens it looks like Write-Output splits the data in chunks and after writing each chunk it triggers the 'data' event and therefore
the psData.stdout.on("data",){} in the node script is triggered, so instead of getting a valid JSON file node gets parts of it and throws an error.

I reckon the Write-Output method splits the data, is there a way to increase its buffer size?

Any other ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Why are you collecting it just to write-output it after? Try letting it just implicitly output and see if that makes a difference

Comment: @ Doug Maurer, if you mean run the powershell script on its own then I did test it, it prints to the console without slicing the data

Comment: No I mean remove `$data =` and `Write-Output $data` so it’s just `$data | ConvertTo-Json`

Comment: @ Doug Maurer, tried it, problem persists

Comment: Worth a shot. @bitbar

Comment: Could not find info on how to change the Write-Output, so looks like I'm going to have to use some workaround.
 
I'm thinking of making the while loop trigger a (custom) event. Do you know how that could be done?